# Passing a String between Fragments

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following code to retrieve a column with numerical values from my database. I want to get the sum of the numeric value and assign it to a string so I can call it in another fragment. How to I assign it to a String? Do I use shared preferences?

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase2.rawQuery(
    "SELECT SUM(COL_VALUES) FROM myTable", null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    return cursor.getInt(0);
}
```

Comment: you can use shared preferences or, if intra intent you can use bundle or extra to be passed between intent

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! How do i assign it to a string so i can call it using shared preferences ?

Comment: Pls use proper tags for the question. sqlite != mysql  Google lead me to this question when I was searching for mysql android

Answer (score 0):

Create a global String and set it to this:

```
String intAsString = String.valueof(cursor.getInt(0));
```

public static String valueOf(int value)

Returns the string representation of the given int.

Hope it helps you.